# Why is 0.0 multiplied by +/-Inf NaN?

Tags: floating-point

Why is 0.0 multiplied by +/-Inf NaN but any other finite number multiplied by +/-Inf +/-Inf ?
Check this small program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    constexpr double INF = numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    cout << 0.0 * INF << endl;
    cout << -5.0 * INF << endl;
}
```

It prints:

```
-nan(ind)
-inf
```

Answer (score 0):

This is according to the rules in calculus. Any nonzero number (or infinity) times infinity is still infinity (with appropriate signs), and this makes computations coherent.

On another hand, the indeterminate forms such as 0*∞ or ∞-∞ have no well-defined value and so are considered NaN.

Note that assigning infinity to 0*∞ is neither logical nor possible, as you could not choose a sign, and assigning a finite value would be a terrible mistake.

Answer (score 0):

+/- Infinity * 0 is kind of a paradox.

It's like an unstoppable object vs an unmoveable wall.

Infinity = a number greater than any assignable quantity.

Nothing multiplied a number greater than any assignable quantity does not make too much sense. However +/- infinity multiplied by any finite number will just be a greater number beyond what is assignable.

A simple way of thinking about it is:

- 0 multiplied by anything is 0
- Infinity multiplied by anything infinity
- Therefore 0 * infinity is undefinable/NaN

Comment: I would rather have a mathematical reasoning than a metaphor. For me anything multiplied by 0.0 should be 0.0.

Comment: Anything multiplied by infinity should be infinity - see the problem...
Expanded my answer to illustrate this

Comment: This is not an ultimate justification for me because the rule that everything multiplied by 0.0 should give zero (except NaN) and I think this rule should be in place above the previous rule. There must be deeper reasoning with that.

Comment: Why would that be the case? Infinity is not a number but a concept used to represent an ever increasing value. 0 * infinity is NaN by definition.

Comment: If you're question is on the semantics of why is maths defined as it is better suited for the maths stack exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> [the rule that everything multiplied by 0.0 should give zero (except NaN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77052121/why-is-0-0-multiplied-by-inf-nan#comment135834712_77052208)

This alternative suggested by OP has some reasonableness, yet is not the mainstream consensus.

> Why is 0.0 multiplied by +/-Inf NaN?

More numerical programs found it more useful to return [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) than to return 0.0 as suggested by OP.  Returning 0.0 would make for a more challenging and oft encountered code `0.0 * ∞` detection.

---

The `0.0 * ∞` return value is **not clearly 0.0, ∞, or any particular value**.  There are application specific cases where the return value of 0.0, ∞, NAN, 1.0, ... are the desired result.  For OP's case. 0.0 is preferred.

Floating point arithmetic has, for decades, had the desire to handle extreme cases in a *consistent  and fast* manner since the 1960s/1970s.  To make fast, it needs a hardware implementation.  To make a hardware implementation, a standard is very useful for consistency and garnering wide acceptance.  Correcting hardware is *very* expensive.

Rather than `0.0 * ∞` return 0.0, the standard choose [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) to reflect the ambiguity of the product.  Too many applications would not want `0.0 * ∞` as 0.0 as for them as it is not a sensible answer, even if for OP it is OK.  **NAN is easy to detect**.  In typical applications, **NANs are rare**.

---

To achieve OP's goal, form a special multiplication routine.

```
// Example
double EvM_mult(double a, double b) {
  double product = a * b;
  if (isnan(product)) {
    if (!isnan(a) && !isnan(b)) {
      return 0.0;
      // or maybe to handle signed zero multiplication:
      return copysign(0.0, a) * copysign(0.0, b);
    }
  }
  return product;
}
```

Comment: For me there is no ambiguity. For me, infinity represents all results that exceed the range of finite numbers. And assuming you could represent them, their value times zero would be zero. To me this definition therefore seems arbitrary.

Comment: @EdisonvonMyosotis With " infinity represents all results that exceed the range of finite numbers.", does _finite numbers_ mean the numbers of encodable as a finite floating point value or all mathematically finite numbers?